# Automating scripts, Rscripts

Tags: windows, r, scheduled-tasks, rscript

Im having a lot of trouble of automating my .R files, and im having trouble understand the information regarding it. But here goes:

Im using windows 7 and simply want to automatically run a R.script every morning at 08.00. The .R file spits out the output by itself, so I dont want a separate output-file. I've created a bat-file like this:

```
"C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Scripts\24AR_v1bat.R"
Echo %DATE% %TIME% %ERRORLEVEL% >> C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\scripts\24AR_v1.txt
```

When I run this manually, it works perfectly. Both with/without the:

```
--default-packages=list
```

When I run it through the cmd-window, it works perfectly. Yet when I try to run it through the task-scheduler it runs, but does not work. (I either get a 1 or 2 error in my error-message file).

I've looked at R Introduction - Invoking R from the command line, and help(Rscript) but I still can't manage to get it to work.

NEW EDIT: I found that not doing the MS SQL-call, will let my code run from the scheduler. Not sure if I should make a new question or?

EDIT: Adding the R-script

```
# 24 Hour AR-model, v1 ----------------------------------------------------
#Remove all variables from the workspace
#rm(list=ls())
# Loading Packages
library(forecast)

#Get spot-prices System from 2012-01-01 to today
source("/location/Scripts/SQL_hourlyprices.R")
sys <- data.frame()
sys <- spot
rm(spot)

# Ordering the data, first making a matrix with names: SYS
colnames(sys) <- c("date","hour","day","spot")
hour <-factor(sys[,2])
day <-factor(sys[,3]) 
dt<-sys[,1]
dt<-as.Date(dt)
x<-sys[,4]

q <-ts(x, frequency=24)

x0<- q[hour==0]
x1<- q[hour==1]

x0 <-ts(x0, frequency=7)
x1 <-ts(x1, frequency=7)

# ARIMA MODELS
y0<-Arima(x0,order=c(2,1,0))
y1<-Arima(x1,order=c(2,1,1))

fr0 <- forecast.Arima(y0,h=1)
fr1 <- forecast.Arima(y1,h=1)

h1<-as.numeric(fr0$mean)
h2<-as.numeric(fr1$mean)

day1 <-Sys.Date()+1
atable<-data.frame
runtime<-Sys.time()
atable<-cbind(runtime,day1,h1,h2)
options(digits=4)

write.table(atable,   file="//location/24ar_v1.csv", 
append=TRUE,quote=FALSE, sep=",", row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

But as I said, I can manually run the code with the batch-file and have it work perfectly, yet with the scheduler it won't work.

Comment: Do you get the expected output from your script when you run it from the scheduler?

Comment: Nope, nothing comes out.

Comment: If possible, post the contents of your script file. That could help track down what's going on.

Comment: Also IIRC Rscript.exe doesn't load the methods package, unlike the GUI. See if adding that to your packages list helps.

Comment: Tried adding the methods package, still would not run through scheduler, but fine if I just dobbleclick the batch-file.

Comment: If you can run the script from the command line, then there shouldn't be any problem with the code. It looks like a problem with how you're setting up your task. Are you running cmd.exe and passing it the path to your batch file, or the batch file directly?

Comment: Im not quite sure what your asking, but i've done it with both cmd.exe and passing the path to the batchfile, and i've run the batchfile directly through the explorer window.

Comment: Have you checked what the environment variables are for both situations to see if there are differences? Try sticking `Sys.getenv()` somewhere in your script and comparing the outputs when run from the command line and run as batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying everything, it seems the problem was that I had:

```
source("/location/Scripts/SQL_hourlyprices.R")
```

Where I simply had a SQL-call inside:

```
sqlQuery(dbdata2, "SELECT CONVERT(char(10), [lokaldatotid],126) AS date, 
   DATEPART(HOUR,lokaldatotid) as hour,
   DATENAME(DW,lokaldatotid) as dag,
   pris as spot

     FROM [SpotPriser] vp1
     WHERE  (vp1.boers_id=0)
     AND (vp1.omraade_id=0)
     AND lokaldatotid >='2012-01-01'
     GROUP BY lokaldatotid, pris
     ORDER BY lokaldatotid, hour desc") -> spot
```

When I moved this directly into the script, and deleted the source-line, the scripts would run with the scheduler.

I have no idea why....